# How to add new column to existing sheet with part of the first column

Tags: vba, excel

How add new column to the existing sheet with part of the firs column VBA

Suppose i have below data:

```
Test 12212
Test 6588476
Something 4125
What is this 1254
```

And i want to do this:

```
Column1      Column2
Test         Test 12212
Test         Test 6588476
Something    Something 4125
What         What is this 1254
```

Any help appreciated.

Regards,

Simon

Comment: Look into LEFT() and INSTR() to find the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Create this function in a module:

```
Public Function GetFirstWord(sFull As String) As String
  GetFirstWord = Split(sFull, " ")(0)
End Function
```

Then you can use it in your cell formula like this:

```
=GetFirstWord(B1)
```